# Falling text animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I would like developing an animation with some words falling and bouncing inside a div.
Watch the gif here below.

https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/fs/a584b0119315793.609d0d7f1a0c7.gif

[Gif falling words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TylLc.gif)

I found something similar here
https://codepen.io/priyamal/pen/EodqbQ

````
  See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/priyamal/pen/EodqbQ">
  Untitled</a> by Priya Malhotra (<a href="https://codepen.io/priyamal">@priyamal</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.
</iframe>```
````

Comment: What have you done so far to accomplish this?

Comment: i used this code https://codepen.io/priyamal/pen/EodqbQ